# Stopping a BufferedReader once the external text file is empty JAVA

Tags: java, external, bufferedreader

I've written a code here to read all the lines of a textFile and currently have an inefficient method of ending the program. I would like to read each line of the selected text file until there is nothing left in the file that hasn't been read yet and display each line to the user. I've searched up various methods however most use complex methods, I would like this to be as simple as possible without any advanced methods.

```
package textfilereader;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TextFileReader
{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

       Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

       System.out.println("Please enter the name of the text document you would like to open");
       System.out.println("For example, 'userName.txt'");
       String textFile = scanner.nextLine();

       try (BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("c:/Users/Nicholas/Desktop/"+textFile))) 
       {


            System.out.println("Contents of the file: "+textFile);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                String line = readFile.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);

                if (line.equals(null))
                    {
                        i = 100;
                   //my inefficient method is currently to continue the loop
                   //if "i" is less than 100, this value can be any value
                   //if the line is a null it will set i to be 100 so the 
                   //loop will stop
                    }
            }

            readFile.close();



       }

    }

}
```

Comment: `while ((line = readFile.readLine() != null) {...}` - I strongly suggest you have a look at [Basic IO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and the [JavaDocs for `BufferedReader#readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--)

Comment: `while ((line = readFile.readLine()) != null){..}`

Comment: getting an error message saying "string cannot be converted to boolean"

Comment: except, the first line of the text file is being skipped when im printing the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `while` loop instead of the `for` loop.

An example

```
// ...
String line = null;
while ((line = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
}
readFile.close();
// ...
```

Comment: this works thankyou, however i'd like an explanation as to why you set String line = null

Comment: It's not necessary in this case, but it's more explicit.